# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - Cannot Parse Some Web Pages

Tags: php, parsing, dom, wamp

I am currently trying to use "**PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**" (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to perform some basic web scraping.

It seems to work perfectly well with some sites, but not others. For example, it works with Google.com but not with a JobServe.com search.

```
echo file_get_html('https://www.jobserve.com/gb/en/JobListing.aspx?shid=BB2D6366D16054EF')->plaintext; 
echo file_get_html('http://www.google.com/')->plaintext;
```

Error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in     
C:\wamp\www\PHP_SCRAPER\_jobs\jobs_dom.php on line 11
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0003  365808  {main}( )   ..\jobs_dom.php:0
```

**What is preventing the DOM Parser from reading the site?** Do I need to save a local copy and clean the headers?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use curl to capture the page given you have more options for error checking as an example

```
//Create a curl handle to a non-existing location
$ch = curl_init('http://google.com');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
   // return the value instead of printing the response to browser
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//set a time out
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,20);
//handle redirected pages
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'identity');
//mimick a useragent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0'); 
if (curl_exec($ch) === false) {
    echo 'page not found';//error handling
}
else
{
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a string
    $html->load(curl_exec($ch));
    echo $html
}
```